The login using firebase auth email in flutter occurred Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. mistake
I had some errors using firebase's email login
I have been in the AndroidManifest. XML configuration for android: usesCleartextTraffic = "true" still rerun this mistake, my firebase console Also enable email login
Errors are as follows"

I/FirebaseAuth(21869): Email link sign in for juyiyang@qq.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
W/System  (21869): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(21869): Error getting App Check token;  using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=getOobCode)with exception - An internal error has occurred. [  unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address@80d85b16 ]

Here are some of my configurations
Here's how I call it
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .sendSignInLinkToEmail(
            email: 'juyiyang@qq.com',
            actionCodeSettings: ActionCodeSettings(
                url: 'https://wallpaper-book.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/',
                // This must be true
                handleCodeInApp: true,
                // iOSBundleId: 'com.example.ios',
                androidPackageName: 'com.example.wallpaper_book',
                // installIfNotAvailable
                androidInstallApp: true,
                // minimumVersion
                androidMinimumVersion: '12'))
        .catchError((onError) {
      OtherUtils.showToastInfo('Error sending email verification $onError',
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF7c2eed), textColor: Colors.white);
    }).then((value) {
      Loading.dismiss();
    });
  }

AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="wallpaper_book"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity ......

firebase console


Have you checked your spam folder? I got the same log messages, but turns out the AppResponse was not being sent, but the email was sent to my spam folder.

I checked. There's no mail
